# Sending Data from View to Different Controller without QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass data from View to Controller(From TestView1 to TestController2)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Index", "Sample", new { testId = test }, null)
```

Currently this is sending Data in  `QueryString`. But i need to avoid this and pass data to Controller without Query string ?

How do i achieve without Querystring ?

I searched and most of them were by using Query string. If i missed out on solutions please redirect to correct path.

Thanks

Comment: What is it you want to pass?

Comment: Some integer value...i need to pass ID?

Comment: integer value comes on html render as text, hidden field or what ?

Comment: am loading from the model which was sent by testViewController1

Comment: ok You may assign value in hidden field(with id txt) and then you got this value in java script.  

  `var Id = $("#txt").val();`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to post your data to the controller, if possible? Keeping a form and hidden fields..

e.g http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_posting_to.ashx

Comment: i need to send to differnet contoller. posting to same controller is straight forward !

Comment: You need to do a POST request. normal <a> tags don't do POST. You need to make the request from code (either JavaScript, or server-side in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using Ajax call back. try this method on your link/button

```
@* Your button/link *@
    <input type="button"  onclick='Link1()'" value="Submit" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Link1() {
        var Id = $("#txt").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Test2/Actionname")',
            type: 'post',
            async: true,
            data: { text: Id },
            success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");//Ajax request success
            alert(data);//data from Test/yourAction

            },
            error: function (err) {
            alert("fail");//Ajax request fail
                alert(err.responseText);//error will displayed here
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```